# Why grid item is not expanding to two rows as specified with grid-row-end?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Want to understand why grid item is not expanding to two rows as specified with grid-row-end in the following html?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .grid-container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: auto auto;
          padding: 10px;
      }        
      .grid-container > div {
          border: 1px solid grey;
          text-align: center;
      }        
      .item1 {
          grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>  
      <div>4</div>
    </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

but it does when grid-column-end is set to 2. How can I get square taking first two lines and both columns?

Comment: you just dont see that the first item is spanning 2 rows as the grid-rows are set to fit-content. If you give them a specific height (e.g. `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`) you will see that it is actually spanning 2 rows.

Comment: thank you, that explains it.